# Facebook says my website link redirects to another website, but it doesn't

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, facebook-graph-api, redirect

When I try to share this link (http://saeedreza.me/) on Facebook first it says it's an unsafe link:

> It looks like a link you're sharing might be unsafe. If you can,
>   please remove this link:
>
> saeedreza.me
>
> Note: The unsafe link might be on the page you’re linking to.

I have checked this domain with [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) and it doesn't show any error. I have also checked it with [Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and still no bug or error. It has all the proper meta tags and even the app ID.

I have also checked the link safety with different services and have received no sign of any malicious malware or suspicious script.

After passing a security check, Facebook allows to share/post the link anyways but when you try to click on the link it redirects you to a page with this message:

> You followed a link on facebook.com that redirects to another website:
>   http://saeedreza.me/ You can now continue to this website, or go back
>   to the page that you were on before. Remember, only follow links from
>   sources that you trust.

I have also checked the site to see if it redirects to any other domain but nothing suspicious again!

I have tried to contact them so many different ways but still no luck. 
Has anyone had this experience before? or do you have any suggestion how I may be able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to shorten site URL with goo.gl, it's a link shim feature from FB giving you this warning: https://m.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/link-shim-protecting-the-people-who-use-facebook-from-malicious-urls/10150492832835766/